# String type replace function can't replace with no char

Tags: string

I want to replace the ":"(colon) in the MAC address with no char (remove the ":").

But I can't find any good solution.

String.replace(), can't replace with (void).

**Note: String.replace(':',(char)0)** *//also doesn't work*

String.remove() is ugly and requires that you know exactly where each iteration is (indexOf()), and this method doesn't return anything, it updates the string directly so you have to call : String.remove() for each occurence.

and String.substring() has most of the same problems as remove, except that it does return the substring, so you can do: String.substring(i,l).substring(i2,l)...

```
#include <WiFi.h>
String MAC;
char ssid[] = "WiFi SSID"
char psw[] = "WiFi PSW"
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,psw);
  MAC = WiFi.macAddress();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  Serial.println("MAC Address unformatted")
  Serial.println(MAC);
  String MAC_f = MAC.replace(':', ' ');
  // Now print the MAC without the ":"
  Serial.println(MAC_f);
  // This replaces the ':' with a space.  I want to replace(remove) the ':' with no char
  // Looking for an elegant, simple, 1 liner to accomplish this.
  
  /* This looks horrible */
  MAC_f = MAC.substring(0,2)+MAC.substring(3, 5)+MAC.substring(6, 8)+MAC.substring(9, 11)+MAC.substring(12, 14)+MAC.substring(15, 17);
  /* .remove also looks terrible */
  MAC_f = MAC;
  MAC_f.remove(2,1);
  MAC_f.remove(2,1);
  // ...
  
}
```

Comment: Please do not attempt to answer questions in the comments. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). The comments on this question have been deleted, including the ones about "a special message". Appropriate action has been taken in regard to this message.

Answer (score 3):

Don´t use `String()` manipulations inside `loop()`. It causes heap fragmentation and program failure. Use a char array instead:

```
char MAC[18] = "01:23:45:67:89:AB"; // including terminating zero

for (int src = 0, dst = 0; src < sizeof(MAC); src++)
   if (MAC[src] != ':') MAC[dst++] = MAC[src];
```

Comment: It works because the terminating zero is copied to the end of the modified string

Comment: @Instigator in which way is this inefficient? Do you know what `String.replace()` does?

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Mat, the empty string in C++ is `""`. This works:

```cpp
MAC_f = MAC;
MAC_f.replace(":", "");
```

That being said, I concur with SBF's answer: `String` object are not
friendly with the Arduino's memory. SBF's solution is better than
`String::replace()`.

Comment: @Instigator you know the difference between `'x'` and `"x"`, right. `String.replace()` takes **String** arguments, not char as you wrote. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/replace/

Answer (score 0):

others a right that String is not totally Arduino friendly, WiFi.macAddress() returns String, SO

though written for ESP32 this is an approach i used

```
 // Get the station interface MAC address.
 // @return String MAC, no camas
String getMacAddress(void)
{
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);   // required to read NVR before WiFi.begin()
    uint8_t baseMac[6];
    esp_read_mac( baseMac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA );  // Get MAC address for WiFi station
    char macStr[18] = { 0 };
    sprintf(macStr, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", baseMac[0], baseMac[1], baseMac[2], baseMac[3], baseMac[4], baseMac[5]);
    return String(macStr);
}
// END getMacAddress()
```

Comment: this maybe is how it should be done, but it doesn't answer the question